# Differences in using PHP Curl vs command line curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I am integrating the Badgeville REST API with my PHP 5.3, curl 7.22 application.

The API documentation for BV all uses command line curl calls for their examples.  When I run these examples they work fine.

When I attempt to do the same thing with the PHP Curl class I always get a 500 error from the BV server.

I have tried to do the synonomous functionality with the Advanced Rest Client extension in Chrome.

PHP Curl Example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://sandbox.v2.badgeville.com/api/berlin/[private_api_key]/users.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);

if($this->getRequestType() == 'POST')
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        array(
            'user[name]'    => 'Generic+Username',
            'user[email]'   => 'johndoe%40domainname.com'
        );
    );
}

$response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

Rest Client Example:

> URL:
>   http://sandbox.v2.badgeville.com/api/berlin/[private_api_key]/users.json
>
> POST 
>   No Headers Payload:
>
> user[name]=Generic+Username&user[email]=johndoe%40domainname.com

I have manually created the command line curl call and ran that with `shell_exec()`, but I would REALLY prefer not having to do that.

In my research I found a Drupal [module](http://drupalcode.org/project/badgeville_gamification.git/blob/2f5c27ba3f05651b55d0e8f54d117f441033bc66:/includes/badgeville.php) and all the API calls are done through `fsockopen()` calls.

Is there some way to do successfully make Badgeville calls using the PHP Curl class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out Badgeville has a 500 error when a curl request comes in that has headers set.

Error returning code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://sandbox.v2.badgeville.com/api/berlin/[private_api_key]/users.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);

if($this->getRequestType() == 'POST')
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        array(
            'user[name]'    => 'Generic+Username',
            'user[email]'   => 'johndoe%40domainname.com'
        );
    );
}

$response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

Properly functioning code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://sandbox.v2.badgeville.com/api/berlin/[private_api_key]/users.json');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);

if($this->getRequestType() == 'POST')
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        array(
            'user[name]'    => 'Generic+Username',
            'user[email]'   => 'johndoe%40domainname.com'
        );
    );
}

$response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

SMH